# How to suppress creation of empty <Config> directories in CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I have a project with the following configuration:

```
build\
src\
 - CMakeLists.txt
 - main.cc
test\
 - CMakeLists.txt
 - test.cc
CMakeLists.txt
```

When I generate and build for a "Release" configuration with Visual Studio from the `build` directory, I get:

```
build\
 - Release\
 - src\
    - Release\
       - main.exe
 - test\
    - Release\
       - test.exe
```

(ignoring all the extra CMake generated files/directories)

The top-level `Release` directory is empty because there are no targets built at that level.

What is the simplest way to suppress the creation of this directory? Can this be done without using an `add_custom_command` call to explicitly delete the directory after it's been created?

**Update**

It appears that the top-level Config directories are created by the ALL_BUILD target after all other targets and custom commands are wrapped up. I don't think this can be achieved even with `add_custom_command` or `add_custom_target`.

Any thoughts about getting around this?

Comment: Can the target property RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG> be of any help? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>

Comment: It only changes where `main.exe` and `test.exe` are created. It does not prevent creation of the <CONFIG> directories (at any level in the "CMAKE_BINARY" tree).